# Spark read csv containing nanosecond timestamps

Tags: postgresql, csv, apache-spark, pyspark

I am dumping a Postgres table using a copy command outputting to CSV.

The CSV contains timestamps formatted as such: `2011-01-01 12:30:10.123456+00`.

I'm reading the CSV like

```
df = spark.read.csv(
    "s3://path/to/csv",
    inferSchema=True,
    timestampFormat="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSX",
    ...
)
```

but this doesn't work (as expected). The timestampFormat uses `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` which does not have nanosecond support.

I've tried a lot of variations on the timestampFormat, and they all produce either String columns or misformat the timestamp. Seems like the nanoseconds end up overflowing the seconds and adding time to my timestamp.

I can't apply a schema to the CSV because I don't always know it, and I can't cast the columns because I don't always know which will be timestamps. I also can't cast the timestamp on the way out of Postgres, because I'm just doing `select * ...`.

How can I solve this so I can ingest the CSV with the proper timestamp format?

My first thought was I just had to modify `timestampFormat`, this seems like it's not possible? My second thought is to use `sed` to truncate the timestamp as I'm dumping from Postgres.

I'm using spark 2.3.1.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: If you create a fake dataframe with an example, could be more easy answer it